# bold symbols in eulervm

Tags: texlive, boldmath, eulervm

I use

```
\usepackage{mathpazo,lineno}
```

for my documents.  However, when I need use \mathbold the equal sign and the strict inequality signs (but not $\le$ or $\ge$) become smaller, and the spacing for $\not=$ is wrong.   This is already documented in the eulervm documentation.   Question:  For these handful of signs (equal, strict inequalities, $\not=$) is it possible to redefine them to get them to the right "shape"?  If so, how, and what about e.g. footnotes, subscripts and possibly (section) titles?  Note that this issue arise only arise in conjunction with $\mathbold$.

### Thanks!

edit:  Here is a minimal working example that illustrates the issue:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{mathpazo,eulervm}
\begin{document}
\section{The equation $A+B=C$}

If $A=0$ then $B\ge C$, but not $B> C$.

\boldmath

\section{The equation $A+B=C$}

If $A=0$ then $B\ge C$, but not $B> C$.

\end{document}
```

Comment: As always please provide a full but minimal example that others can copy and test as is. Then we all agre on what we are dealing with.

Comment: in your question you said you used `\mathbold` I assume that's a typo as in the later added example you used `\boldmath`

Comment: it looks like a er feature of the euler font, you see the same without mathpazo

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the bold font in eulervm has the wrong > symbol.

Rather than fix the font, you could select > from somewhere else. In T1 encoding there is a > in the usual place in the text font so perhaps....

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{
  mathpazo,
}
\usepackage[T1]{eulervm}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\DeclareMathSymbol{>}{\mathrel}{operators}{"3E}

\begin{document}
\section{The equation $A+B=C$}

If $A=0$ then $B\ge C$, but not $B> C$.

\boldmath

\section{The equation $A+B=C$}

%\showoutput
If $A=0$ then $B\ge C$, but not $B> C$.

\end{document}
```

Comment: @carlisle:  I am happy to report that this works for >.  But the obvious modificaiton for the equal sign or for \not= does not work:  \DeclareMathSymbol{=}{\mathrel}{operators}{"3E} still gives me the > sign.  I imagine that the secret lies in the "3E but I have no idea what that is.  I'd be most appreciative for your clarification!

Comment: @carlisle:  One more question:  What is the difference between \usepackage[T1]{eulervm}  and   \usepackage{eulervm}  ?  Thanks!

Comment: it uses T1 encoding for the operator font rather than the original OT1 (which has a Spanish inverted punctuation in the `<` slot, try it. @underflow

Comment: @carlisle:  I did some digging and find that using {"3D} will give me the correct equal sign, and {"3C"}, the correct < sign.  Now I just need \not=  --- what is the correct "code" for \not=?  Thanks!

Comment: the text font won't have a not = sorry you could try defining \neq as \not=